# R lidR CRS as WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, r, lidr

I would like to solve the warning I receive when I read in a set of laz files using `readLASCatalog` in the R package `lidR`.

When I use this code I receive this warning:

```r
library(lidR)
ctg_test <- readLAScatalog ("c:/temp/t/laz")
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: This LAS object stores the CRS as WKT. 0 returned; use 'wkt()' instead.
```

When I look at one of the laz files,

```r
las = readLAS("c:/Temp/t/laz/in2018_28402265_12.laz")
#> Warning message:
#> There are 748 points flagged 'withheld'.
```

More details

```r
las
#> class        : LAS (v1.4 format 6)
#> memory       : 788.5 Mb 
#> extent       : 2840000, 2845000, 2265000, 2270000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : NAD83(HARN) / Indiana West (ftUS) + NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (ftUS) (with axis order normalized for visualization) (with axis order normalized for visualization) 
#> area         : 25 kus-ft²
#> points       : 8.99 million points
#> density      : 0.36 points/us-ft²
```

```r
las@header
#> File signature:           LASF 
#> File source ID:           0 
#> Global encoding:
#>  - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
#>  - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
#>  - Well Know Text: CRS is WKT 
#>  - Aggregate Model: false 
#> Project ID - GUID:        b601ab3f-37a8-43c3-328d-f1f5a00b66e4 
#> Version:                  1.4
#> System identifier:        Woolpert LAS 
#> Generating software:      GeoCue LAS Updater 
#> File creation d/y:        248/2018
#> header size:              375 
#> Offset to point data:     1483 
#> Num. var. length record:  1 
#> Point data format:        6 
#> Point data record length: 30 
#> Num. of point records:    8986941 
#> Num. of points by return: 8073636 687316 199022 25963 1004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
#> Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01 
#> Offset X Y Z:             0 0 0 
#> min X Y Z:                2840000 2265000 573.24 
#> max X Y Z:                2845000 2270000 2086.6 
#> Variable length records: 
#>    Variable length record 1 of 1 
#>        Description: OGC WKT Coordinate System 
#>        WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM: COMPD_CS["NAD83(HARN) / Indiana West (ftUS) + NAVD88 height - Geoid12B [...] (truncated)
```

Where/how exactly do I use `wkt()` in my catalog function to remedy the warnings I receive? I am using version 3.1.1 of the `lidR` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small issue in `readLAScatalog()`. LAS format 1.4 is not supported as well as LAS formats < 1.4. An other related question has been asked few days ago ([R lidR does not read the CRS of my las file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385739/r-lidr-does-not-read-the-crs-of-my-las-file)). `lidR >= 3.1.2` will have a better support of LAS 1.4. And with `rlas 1.4` it will have an even better support.

Meanwhile you can simply get rid of the warning:

```r
ctg_test <- suppressWarnings(readLAScatalog("c:/temp/t/laz"))
```

Notice that the CRS is not read by `readLAScatalog()` because of the issue mentioned. Something like that may work if the WKT string is valid which is often not the case I believe.

```r
h = readLASheader(ctg_test$filename[1])
crs = sp::CRS(SRS_string = wkt(h))
projection(ctg_test) <- crs
```

Comment: Bug fixed and available in lidR 3.1.2 on gihub