# Reading CRS using lidR

Tags: coordinate-system, r, lidr

I have a similar issue that reported here: [R lidR does not read the CRS of my las file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385739/r-lidr-does-not-read-the-crs-of-my-las-file). `lidR` cannot read the CRS while lasinfo from lastools can.

```r
readLAS("USGS_LPC_MS_Tupelo_UTM15_2015_15RYQ605365_LAS_2016.laz")
#> proj_create: crs not found
#> proj_create: crs not found
#> class        : LAS (v1.2 format 1)
#> memory       : 253.4 Mb 
#> extent       : 761421.7, 762000, 3436500, 3438000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : NA 
#> area         : 0.84 kunits²
#> points       : 3.32 million points
#> density      : 3.97 points/units²
```

But the LAS file is not 1.4 (1.2) and the use of `rlas` 1.4 and `lidR` 3.2 from github don't help. The laz file can be found [here](ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/LPC/Projects/USGS_LPC_MS_Tupelo_UTM15_2015_LAS_2016/laz/USGS_LPC_MS_Tupelo_UTM15_2015_15RYQ605365_LAS_2016.laz)

Comment: Helps to add the R tag - some of us search for it and we'd miss this otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `LAStools` nor `lidR` understand the CRS properly. But `lasinfo` displays more information read in the header.

`lidR` uses the key 3072 in the GeoTiff Projection Keys which is exected to be the epsg code. In your case it contains 32767 which is not a valid epsg code.

```r
sp::CRS(SRS_string = "ESPG:32767")
#> Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = "ESPG:32767") : NA
```

In your case the header contains much more than the EPSG code so maybe there is something you can use to build a valid CRS. But there is nothing that can be parsed automatically in R (as far as I know) except the epsg code.

```r
library(lidR)
readLASheader("USGS_LPC_MS_Tupelo_UTM15_2015_15RYQ605365_LAS_2016.laz")
#> File signature:           LASF 
#> File source ID:           0 
#> Global encoding:
#>  - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
#>  - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
#>  - Well Know Text: CRS is GeoTIFF 
#>  - Aggregate Model: false 
#> Project ID - GUID:        1388176b-ba63-483e-1485-144d0f79a00a 
#> Version:                  1.2
#> System identifier:        Woolpert ALS70 Merged 
#> Generating software:      GeoCue LAS Updater 
#> File creation d/y:        326/2015
#> header size:              227 
#> Offset to point data:     897 
#> Num. var. length record:  3 
#> Point data format:        1 
#> Point data record length: 28 
#> Num. of point records:    3320964 
#> Num. of points by return: 2040179 984218 261869 32880 1789 
#> Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01 
#> Offset X Y Z:             0 0 0 
#> min X Y Z:                761421.7 3436500 86.85 
#> max X Y Z:                762000 3438000 141.06 
#> Variable Length Records (VLR):
#>    Variable Length Record 1 of 3 
#>        Description: GeoTiff Projection Keys 
#>        Tags:
#>           Key 1024 value 1 
#>           Key 1026 value 59 
#>           Key 2048 value 32767 
#>           Key 2049 value 124 
#>           Key 2050 value 32767 
#>           Key 2051 value 8901 
#>           Key 2054 value 9102 
#>           Key 2055 value 9 
#>           Key 2056 value 7019 
#>           Key 2057 value 6 
#>           Key 2059 value 7 
#>           Key 2061 value 8 
#>           Key 3072 value 32767 
#>           Key 3073 value 0 
#>           Key 3074 value 32767 
#>           Key 3075 value 1 
#>           Key 3076 value 9001 
#>           Key 3077 value 5 
#>           Key 3081 value 0 
#>           Key 3082 value 1 
#>           Key 3083 value 2 
#>           Key 3088 value 3 
#>           Key 3092 value 4 
#>           Key 4097 value 97 
#>           Key 4099 value 9001 
#>    Variable Length Record 2 of 3 
#>        Description: GeoTiff double parameters 
#>        data: 0 5e+05 0 -93 0.9996 1 6378137 298.2572 0 0.01745329 
#>    Variable Length Record 3 of 3 
#>        Description: GeoTiff ASCII parameters 
#>        data: NAD_1983_2011_UTM_Zone_15N|projection: Transverse Mercator|PCS Name = NAD_1983_2011_UTM_Zone_15N|NAVD88 - Geoid12A (Meters)|GCS Name = GCS_NAD_1983_2011|Datum = NAD_1983_2011|Ellipsoid = GRS_1980|Primem = Greenwich| 
#> Extended Variable Length Records (EVLR):  void
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>